# Effective way to find and delete certain elements from a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array with some positive numbers and some `-1` elements. I want to find these elements with `-1` values, delete them and store their indeces.

One way of doing it is iterating through the array and cheking if the value is `-1`. Is this the only way? If not, what about its effectivness? Isn't there a more effective python tool then?

Comment: You can use Using `np.where` and a simple indexing. You'll find a lot of similar question in SO if you search thoroughly. (`np.where(a==-1)` and `a[a != -1]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `numpy.argwhere()` and `numpy.delete()` routines:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, -1, 4, -1, 5, 10, -1, 14])
indices = np.argwhere(arr == -1).flatten()
new_arr = np.delete(arr, indices)

print(new_arr)            # [ 1  2  3  4  5 10 14]
print(indices.tolist())   # [3, 5, 8]
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
yourarray=np.array([4,5,6,7,-1,2,3,-1,9,-1]) #say
rangenumpyarray=np.arange(len(yourarray)) # to create a column adjacent to your array of range
arra=np.hstack((rangenumpyarray.reshape(-1,1),yourarray.reshape(-1,1))) # combining both arrays as two columns
arra[arra[:,1]==-1][:,0]  # learn boolean indexing
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `np.flatnonzero` and simple *boolean indexing*.

```
x = array([ 0,  0, -1,  0,  0, -1,  0, -2,  0,  0])
m = x != -1  # generate a mask

idx = np.flatnonzero(~m)
x = x[m]
```

```
idx
array([2, 5])

x
array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -2,  0,  0])
```